# Two git-svn repository clones, new commits doesn't appear

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have a SVN server `S1`. I fetched repository on two computers `PC1` and `PC2`. I added git commits on `PC1` thanks to `git commit` and then put them to server through `svn dcommit`. Everything looks fine. Changes are on server. Next i went to `PC2` and tried 'git svn fetch'. It fetched last commit(I hope so because terminal output looked like it fetched), but i don't see last commit in log. Also i doesn't see new changes in files.

Maybe the problem is connected with way that i've made my two repositories. Repository on `PC1` was made thanks to `git svn`. But repository on `PC2` was a hardcopy(through `scp -rf`) from `PC1`.

What it's wrong ?

Comment: Do i have to use `git push` when my repo server is svn server? I thought that `git svn dcommit` does this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... Now i used `git rebase` on `PC2` and my files changed to the newest revision that i posted yesterday on `PC1`. Interesting.

Ok so this was a solution. To update repo on `PC2` with changes made on `PC1` I have to

```
git svn fetch
git stash
git svn rebase
git stash apply
```

Edit : Yes, only `git svn rebase` does it's job!

Comment: You can even leave out the `fetch`, the `rebase` will `fetch` first. `git svn fetch` is like `git fetch`, it fetches the latest changes into the remote tracking branch, but does not mangle with your local branches.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` gets revisions from remote to local repository, but doesnt update your working directory. See `git log --graph --all` and please read some git tutorials.